# How to make Java JFileChooser display all files including ones starting with a dot

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, jfilechooser, dotfiles

By default `JFileChooser` does not display files with names starting with at dot. How to make it display all files?

Here is what I have tried (did not help):

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "All Files";
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JFilechooser setFileHidingEnabled()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileHidingEnabled%28boolean%29)

```
chooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
```

[How to Use File Chooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)